# Showing $1$ is a limit of a sequence

Tags: calculus, limits, probability-limit-theorems

Let $x_n$ be a sequence such that:
$x_1 = {3 \over 2}$ and $x_n = {3 \over {4-x_{n-1}}}$.

I already showed by induction that $x_n$ is strictly decreasing and bounded below by $1$. Is is suffice in order to prove $1$ is the **limit** of $x_n$? Should I also show that $1$ is the greatest lower bound?

Comment: It isn't sufficient, $a_n = 2 + \frac{1}{n}$ is also strictly decreasing and bounded below by $1$. You need to show that $1$ is the greatest lower bound to conclude that $1$ is the limit.

Comment: OK, thanks. By the way I know that in this phase I can use limit arithmetic (because we know the limit exists) and that's just solving a quadratic equation.

Comment: Yes, that works too here.

Comment: Consider that if it is bounded below by 1 then it is also bounded below by 0, -1, etc. So a lower bound is clearly not the same as a limit. Other posts point in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not suffice to prove that 1 is the limit of $x_n$. but you know that $x_n$ is strictly decreasing and that it is bounded. this implies that the limit of this sequence exists. Hint: Further should be $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} x_{n+1}$.

Answer (score 1):

By the monotone convergence theorem, if a sequence is decreasing and bounded below by an *infimum*, the sequence will converge to the infimum.